# Página de erro 500 retornada invés de página de erro do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, página-de-erro, handler

Não sei por qual motivo os erros não são renderizados no meu projeto, simplesmente não passa pelo método handler.

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
<?php

 $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
       realpath(__DIR__ . '/../')
 );

$app->singleton(
      Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class, 
      App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
      Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
      App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
      Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,   
      App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

return $app;
```

**app/Exception/Handler.php.php**

```php
 namespace App\Exceptions;

 use Exception;
 use GrahamCampbell\Exceptions\ExceptionHandler as ExceptionHandler;

 class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

protected $dontReport = [
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
];

public function report(Exception $e) {
    return parent::report($e);
}

public function render($request, Exception $e) {
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }

        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\JsonResponseHandler());
        } else {
            $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());
        }

        return new \Illuminate\Http\Response(
                $whoops->handleException($e), $e->getStatusCode(), $e->getHeaders()
        );
}
```

Já tentei fazer de diversas formas, quando o erro é 404 e eu coloco este trecho no handler, ele funciona:

```php
 if (method_exists($e, 'getStatusCode') && $e->getStatusCode() == 404)
      return redirect('/erro');
 return parent::render($request, $e);
```

Porém estou tentando fazer uma divisão por 0 para forçar o erro e de forma alguma funciona no primeiro exemplo, outros erros que já tive durante o desenvolvimento também não são tratados.

Comment: Original do Laravel

Comment: Estou forçando apenas pra testar, na verdade nenhum erro é renderizado...hehe

Comment: Na verdade quero renderizar o erro com o "filp/whoops", que pelo que acabei de descobrir que não é mais nativo a partir do laravel 5.

Comment: Justamente, meu problema não são com os erros 404, este são tratados de boa, quero renderizar os erros para poder debugar...

Comment: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/31a4e1410e740fd0ccda128cbcab8723f45e7e73/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f305651706539362e706e67

Comment: Kenny eu baixei o Whoops e coloquei no meu routes assim pra testar `Route::get('/others/blog/', function () {
    abort(500);
    return 'Olá';
});` e funcionou... Como é o teste que está fazendo com o erro 500? Note que o meu .env está assim `APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true` (outro detalhe estou usando a versão 2.0, você está usando o 1.1?)

Comment: Meu .env está assim tmb, e a versão também é 2.0

Comment: E como você está emitindo o erro 500? Eu fiz um teste na index assim também: `Route::get('/', function () { abort(500); return 'Olá'; });` e funcionou.

Comment: Eu fiz uma divisão por zero numa action mesmo...

Comment: Tentei um abort(500); mas também não deu

Comment: Entendi, você quer interceptar os Exceptions, aqui funcionou normal, quanto pesa teu projeto?

Comment: então... 10gb... =P

Comment: Eu testei aqui divisão por 0 e funcionou: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OoxHN.png - só consigo supor que foi algum erro seu, me chama no chat Estouro de Pilha amanhã.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema, um usuário de outro fórum sugeriu que devido ao Laravel 5 ainda não estar estável (cerca de 7 meses antes de agora), deveria ter feito a seguinte alteração:

**bootstrap\app.php**

De:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

Para:

```php
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

Problem solved! =)

Comment: Creio que muitos ainda possam passar por essa situação.